# Manage repetitive/similar structures (logging & try/catch blocks)

Tags: javascript, logging

I'm writing a web bot using [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) and I'm logging (using [winston](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston)) every action the bots does and running it inside try/catch blocks.

For automating these processes and avoid code repetition I created this function:

```
module.exports = {

  webAction: async function (logger, msg, func, ...args)
  {
    return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
      let actionMessage, actionLevel;
      try
      {
        await func(...args);
        actionMessage = msg;
        actionLevel = 'info';
      }
      catch (error)
      {
        actionMessage = "Error while executing (" + msg + ") function.\n---\n" + error.message + "\n---";
        actionLevel = 'error';
      }
      finally
      {
        logger.log({
          level: actionLevel,
          message: actionMessage
        })
      }
      resolve('Fullfilment value of Promise');

    })
  },
```

I use the previous function with arrow functions and normal/regular functions as arguments for making it as dynamic as it can be:

```
const htmlCode = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('*').outerHTML);
await utils.webAction(
  logger, 'Save web code as html file',
  (() => (utils.saveStrAsFile('htmlCodeMP_NewItem.html', htmlCode)))
);

let titleID, priceID;
await utils.webAction(
  logger, 'Find Ids',
  (() => ([titleID, priceID] = utils.findDynamicIdsMP(htmlCode)))
);

await utils.webAction(
  logger, 'Enter item title', utils.webType,
  page, 'FooTitle', `input[id="${titleID}"]`  // Arguments of `webType`
);
await utils.webAction(
  logger, 'Enter item price', utils.webType,
  page, '1234', `input[id="${priceID}"]`  // Arguments of `webType`
);
await utils.webAction(
  logger, 'Click item category dropdown menu',
  (() => (page.click(constants.cssMpCreateItemCategory))),
);
```

Is this a good practice?

I honestly thinks it avoids a lot repetition of code (at least the try/catch blocks & the logger block).

But on the other part I'm thinking that there must be a better approach or professional way of doing this.

I'm no professional nor skilled in Javascript, I'm an amateur in Javascript.

Any advice is highly appreciated/

Thanks in advanced ;)

Comment: The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state **the task accomplished by the code**. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing in arguments as a list of arguments into `webAction` becomes hard to read. My suggestion would be as follows

1. Make the arguments an object
2. Make the `func` a callback that is invoked with no arguments. Don't have `webAction` know anything about what function it is running
3. `return` the `func`'s `return` value in `webAction`.

```js
const utils = {
    webAction: async ({ logger, msg, func }) => {
        return new Promise(async (resolve) => {
            let res
            let actionMessage, actionLevel
            try {
                res = await func()
                actionMessage = msg
                actionLevel = 'info'
            }
            catch (error) {
                actionMessage = "Error while executing (" + msg + ") function.\n---\n" + error.message + "\n---"
                actionLevel = 'error'
            }
            finally {
                logger.log({
                    level: actionLevel,
                    message: actionMessage,
                })
            }
            resolve(res)
        })
    },
}
```

Notice how `func` is invoked with no arguments. Then in its usage:

```javascript
const htmlCode = await page.evaluate(() => document.querySelector('*').outerHTML);
await utils.webAction({
    logger,
    msg: 'Save web code as html file',
    func: () => utils.saveStrAsFile('htmlCodeMP_NewItem.html', htmlCode)
})

const [titleID, priceID] = await utils.webAction({
    func: () => utils.findDynamicIdsMP('htmlCode'),
    logger,
    msg: 'Find Ids',
})

await utils.webAction({
    func: () => utils.webType(page, 'FooTitle', `input[id="${titleID}"]`),
    logger,
    msg: 'Enter item title',
})
```